# Unable to configure Powercenter 10.2 Computing connection with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, informatica-powercenter

As I indicated in the title, I am installing the Powercenter Computing tool (informatica_1020_server_winem-64t downloaded from the Oracle page), in Windows 10 Home and when I want to configure the connection to the SQL Server 2008 database, it gives me an error that does not say too much , only the test failed.

I have the SQL server installed locally on my machine, a base (IPC) and a "pwc" user with Admin permissions were created. Remote connection is enabled.

As computer uses JDBC to connect, do I need to have any extra settings?

The version of JDBC for sql server that you download is: 6.0 and 7.4, but it's still the same. If someone can guide me to see what happens, I would greatly appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgenj.jpg)

Comment: You say you're using Windows 10 and SQL Server 2008. Your connection string says you're connecting to the localhost (`127.0.0.1`) meaning it is impossible for you to be running Windows 10 and SQL Server 2008 (as the latter does not run on the former). This makes me think you don't actually have SQL Server installed.

Comment: select @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: NT6.2 is Server 2012...

Comment: RTM? Good grief, at least install the latest SP for that completely unsupported version.

Comment: @Smor raises a good point. Why *haven't* you patched that server once in 11 years..? There are multiple known security issues in 2008 RTM

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6000.29 (X64)   Sep  3 2014 04:11:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 18362: )
Ok friends, update the database. Can you help me now? Thank you.